# SQL timestamp between hours that fall across midnight

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find all records that would fall with in a current time period based on the current time. For example the current time is 12:30am and I need all the records from the previous day starting at 6:00pm till current time. Very new to SQL and any help would be appreciated.

Below is a screenshot of the table and the column of interest is the timestamp (datetime). I have not tried really anything concrete, am still struggling with just trying to figure out how I would go about it.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCUPW.png)

Comment: You should at least show your table structure, the column of interest with its data type, and most importantly: what you have tried so far.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query returns "yesterday at 6 PM":

```
select DATEADD(hh, -6, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

The inner DATEADD gets "today at midnight" (basically just truncates the time part from "now".  Try running the following by itself to see this:

```
select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

The outer DATEADD then subtracts 6 hours from "today at midnight" to get "yesterday at 6 PM".

So, to get all records from a table with a time greater than yesterday at 6 PM you would put this expression in a WHERE clause, like this:

```
select * from MyTable 
where MyDateField > DATEADD(hh, -6, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

The options to manipulate dates in SQL are limited only by your imagination :)

For example, in your comment below, you want to filter on "current shift", which could be 6AM-6PM or 6PM-6AM, depending on current time. This would be more complicated, but still doable, like this:

```
select * from MyTable
where MyDateField >= 
    case 
    when datepart(hh, getdate()) < 6 then -- if before 6AM
        --yesterday at 6 PM
        dateadd(hh, -6, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
    when datepart(hh, getdate()) between 6 and 18 then -- if between 6AM and 6PM
        --today at 6 AM
        dateadd(hh, 6, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
    else -- if after 6 PM
        --today at 6 PM
        dateadd(hh, 18, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
    end
and MyDateField < 
    case 
    when datepart(hh, getdate()) < 6 then -- if before 6AM
        --today at 6 AM
        dateadd(hh, 6, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
    when datepart(hh, getdate()) between 6 and 18 then -- if between 6AM and 6PM
        --today at 6 PM
        dateadd(hh, 18, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
    else -- if after 6 PM
        --tomorrow at 6 AM
        dateadd(hh, 30, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0))
    end
```

Notice how this reuses the same calculation for "today at midnight" and simply adds a variable number of hours to that, depending on the current hour of the day, which is where `datepart` comes in handy.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't think I explained it right, basically I have two shifts 6:00am to 6:00pm and 6:00pm to 6:00 am. Depending on which shift I'm currently on I only want to grab records that are timestamped for that current shift.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Now to make sure I understand it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

select dateadd(hour,-6,cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))

This may be a bit convoluted, but the above is getting the current date and going back 6 hours. This will return 6PM from "yesterday".

You could take records where TIMESTAMP > the above.